# How to use ffmpeg with h.265 (or h.264) codec?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, h.265

Normally I start recording the camera image with the command:

`ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 OUT.mp4`

but I'm not sure which coded do I use in here (I'm just beginning my adventure with ffmpeg), however I found on [this webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/785528/how-to-generate-an-mp4-with-h-265-codec-using-ffmpeg) this command:

`ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mov`

But when I run it - I get the following error:
`INPUT: No such file or directory"`

I changed the INPUT word above also to `0`, so the command is

`ffmpeg -i 0 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 OUT.mov`,
but error stays similar (`0: no such file or directory`).
How can I grab the camera image and save it to a file while using the [H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get a better understanding of how `ffmpeg` works and what each parameter means. The documentation [is here](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html), have fun.

In your case:

```
          |------ input ------||----- output ------|

ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 -c:v libx265 out.mp4
```

Your *input* is a `vfwcap` device with the ID `0` which captures at a rate of `25 fps`. Your *output* is a `mp4` file containing a video stream encoded with `libx265`.

If you use `-i 0` wihtout a format it assumes you're trying to input a file, and it obviously can't find that file.

For all this to work you need to have the `x265` encoder installed on your system and FFmpeg [compiled with](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) `libx265` support.